# Rails: validate all date fields in all models globally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on an issue where we have a large number of models with date fields. Looking for a way to have a validation that applies to all date fields across the project, and validates the date is before Dec 31, 9999.

The only solutions I have found involve going through and adding specific validations to each model, but my project lead would prefer a cleaner single-location solution and I can’t find anything that does this.

Comment: Please share some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a base class

```
class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :date, presence: true
end
```

Then every model inherits the base class

Comment: Thanks, this works really well since we are moving to Rails 5.0 and I can just edit the ApplicationRecord to add the validation. http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/12/28/application-record-in-rails-5.html